# How to add a tiff image x/y resolution tags in java?

Tags: java, image, tiff

I am facing this issue http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IO10129.

Here resolution tag of the image is missing.
Now I want to add a tiff x/y resolution tags to the image.